# jQgrid with dynamic column name does not showing data

Tags: jqgrid

I am trying to load jQgrid with dynamic column name. following is my code. problem is column name is loading dynamically but data is not showing. i have tried with some different ways with no success.

```
  function onSuccess(jsonData) {

        var dataModel = [];

        for (prop in jsonData[0]) {

                dataModel.push({
                        label: prop,
                        name: prop,
                        index: prop,
                        width: 100,
                        sortable: true,
                        hidden: false
                    });


         }
         $("#tblPayrollEmployee").jqGrid({
                     data: jsonData,
                     colModel: dataModel,
                     viewrecords: true, 
                     width: 780,
                     height: 200,
                     rowNum: 15,
                     datatype: 'local',
                     pager: "#jqGridPager",
                     caption: "dynamin grid"
        });
  });
```

**jsonData structure**

[image]

**dataModel structure** 
[image]

Comment: What is the structure of `prop`? From what I understand, you should do something like
`dataModel.push({
                        label: prop.label,
                        name: prop.name,
                        index: prop.index,
                        width: 100.width,
                        sortable: true,
                        hidden: false
                    });`

Comment: Please include **always** the information about the version of jqGrid which you use (or can use) and the fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). I develop free jqGrid fork, which I can recommend you to use. **The test  data** (`jsonData` and `dataModel`) are required**. It's important to know which property can be used as the **unique id** of the items (it seems be `Id` in your case).

Comment: prop is the name of lebel, name and index.please see jsonData structure in the given image

Comment: i am using jqgrid version 4.0.0

Comment: One can't use cut&paste to include the data from the picture to the demo. **You should include the test value of `jsonData` so that it can be used by other in the demo, which reproduces the problem.** Why you use such old version of jqGrid? 4.0.0 is **five and half years old**. It's published at the time of Chrome 9, Firefox 3.6 and IE8. Now one uses Chrome 54, Firefox 50, Microsoft Edge 38 and IE11. Do you really believe that the old version can work good in modern web browsers? Which versions of jQuery and jQuery UI you use? Some retro versions too or an aktuelle version?

Comment: The code which you posted calls `$("#tblPayrollEmployee").jqGrid({...})` **in the loop**, which is wrong. You want probably to fill `dataModel` in the loop and *then* make *one call* of `$("#tblPayrollEmployee").jqGrid({...})`. Moreover the input data contains properties which contains spaces. It's the problem, especially for old versions of jqGrid. New version can use `jsonmap` property of `colModel` with local data (`datatype: 'local'`). Thus you can use `jsonmap: "Mohammad Obaidur Rahan "` and use *another* `name` property (`name: "MohammadObaidurRahan"` or just `name: "c123"`, for example)